# Is it possible to pass an empty Platform::Array<uint8> into an Event delegate?

Tags: c#, c++-cx

I am using C++-CX to write a windows runtime component, for windows phone 8 (and consuming the component in C#).

In the Cx side I am building some `Platform::Array<uint8>` objects, and I am trying to pass them back into the C# side using an Event/Delegate.

This works fine when the arrays are not empty, for example:

```
public delegate void DataReceivedFunction(const Array<uint8>^ a, const Array<uint8>^ b);
...
// public member
event DataReceivedFunction^ DataReceivedEvent;

...
// Inside some function
// Build a byte array with 5 elements
Array<uint8>^ five = ref new Array<uint8>(5);

// Build an empty array
Array<uint8>^ empty = ref new Array<uint8>(0);

DataReceivedEvent(five, empty);
```

Stepping through the code the empty array gets created successfully and has a length of zero, so it isn't null when passed to the DataReceivedEvent.

But on the C# side the empty array is not a `byte[0]` but rather `null`. The other array works as you would expect.

I am guessing that the Cx layer is being smart and assuming it can free this object since it doesn't contain any bytes? Does anyone have any experience with this?

(It can be worked around in the C# side for sure, but as a rule I do not like to return `null` objects where an empty object will do.)

Comment: Is there an actual use case for passing an empty array from C++/CX up to the C# or just something you are curious about? I'd agree with you that the C++/CX is nulling the object because it's empty

Comment: In designing an SDK I would rather pass an empty byte array to the user than a null reference. Call it a stylistic choice, but this is how our SDK behaves on other platforms i.e. objC, java, javascript.  The reasoning is because the user code does not need to explicitly check for a null value, if you have code which loops over the array it will simply not perform any actions since the array length is already zero. If you have code which converts to a string, it will make an empty string, not crash due to a null pointer reference, and so on.

Comment: Whether this behavior is desirable or not, it would be great if somebody could point me to any documentation, because I can't find it, and I would hate to be in some way relying upon undocumented behavior!